# Pod install results to `home': couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode9

I am trying to install pods for my iOS project using

```
pod install
```

It results in the following error

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.3.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:23:in `home': couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)

        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.3.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:23:in `<class:Config>'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.3.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:6:in `<module:Pod>'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.3.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.3.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:23:in `<module:Pod>'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.3.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.3.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.3.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.3.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

What does this error mean and how can I solve it? Any suggestions appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Type command `env` to check if HOME path exist.
2. If not, move to ~/.bash_profile and add：
   HOME = "users/#(your_user_name)"
   export HOME
3. Type command `source .bash-profile` to write back.

Thats's all I know, hope it will work.